# notifyPropertyChange does not notify bound property chain

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have an object that gets updated that ember is unable to notice a change since it's updating a nested attribute. I am letting it know that a change has in fact happened by calling notifyPropertyChange. However, my parent view is not getting the notification that its bound attribute changed.

Example:
http://emberjs.jsbin.com/qesemahi/3/edit

---

I have a bad hack to get around this but I am hoping there is a reason ember does not notify the entire bound chain. Currently I have a bad clone the object: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/qesemahi/4/edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because data is a reference inside of your component, it's telling the reference in your component that it's changed.  Honestly it seems like you are trying to manually handle property changes, despite the fact that Ember has this built in.

```
App.IndexController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  display: function() {
    return this.get('data.underneath');
  }.property('data.underneath')
});


App.MyComponentComponent =  Ember.Component.extend({
  display: function() {
    return this.get('data.underneath');
  }.property('data.underneath'),
  actions: {
    insideClick: function(){
      this.set('data.underneath', 'foo bar');       
    }
  }
});
```

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/qesemahi/6/edit

This can be even cleaner using computed aliases..

```
App.IndexController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  display: Ember.computed.alias('data.underneath')
});


App.MyComponentComponent =  Ember.Component.extend({
  display: Ember.computed.alias('data.underneath'),
  actions: {
    insideClick: function(){
      this.set('data.underneath', 'foo bar');
    }
  }
});
```